# Javascript Animation not working properly in IE7 or 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, jquery-animate

I am trying to get a javascript animation to work in IE 7 and 8. It is a self-starting animation that uses pauses and delays to time the sequence of object fadeins. it works fine in FF AND Safari but in IE 7/8 instead of following the timing and sequence of the fade ins, all of the elements are visible on page load. Not sure what could be the problem. Any help would be great,Thanks!

link to animation: http://pushdesign.net/medley/ie/

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying to default opacity to 0 with this:

```
.segment { opacity: 0 }
```

IE does not respect `opacity` - you have to include the non-standard `filter`:

```
.segment { opacity: 0 
           filter: alpha(opacity = 0); }
```

the range for `alpha(opacity=x...y)` is 0 to 100, although 0 is all you need here since you want things to be totally invisible.

Comment: That was it! wow that was simple. i didn't even think about that. I thought it was something to do with the javascript. Thanks so much for your help!